# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on this linked list creation?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am very new to C and I am not understanding where the segmentation fault is occurring in my code. I am just trying to create a linked list which will be the type unit for a hash table. I understand that I probably didn't use a malloc where I was supposed to. The main function will run but as soon as I add one item I get the segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct word_link
{
    char* val;
    struct word_link * next;
} word_link;

void add_to_list(char* word, word_link *head);

void add_to_list(char* word, word_link *head){

  int i;
  word_link * temp = NULL;
  word_link * p = NULL;

  temp = (word_link*)malloc(sizeof(word_link));
  temp->val = word;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
  } else {
    p = head;
    while(p->next != NULL){
      p = p->next;
    }
    p->next = temp;
  }
}
void main() {

  int i = 0;
  struct word_link *lst = malloc(sizeof(word_link));
  char* word = "";
  while(i == 0){
  printf("what to add?  ");
  scanf("%s",word);
  add_to_list(word, lst);
  printf("continue?  ");
  scanf("%d", i);
  }
  printf("%s", lst->val);
  printf("%s", "asdf;kl");
}
```

Comment: `head = temp;` does not change `lst` in `main()`.  Also review `char* word = ""; ... 
  scanf("%s",word);`.  Perhaps other issues too.  Strongly recommend to compile with all warnings enabled.  That good expected feedback is faster than posting on SO.

Comment: There are numerous bugs that strongly suggest that you are not familiar with the memory model of C (and strings, and call-per-value parameters, etc.).
First of all, you may find the following helpful: Memory debugger (e.g., valgrind), a static code analyzer (e.g., clang-check, cppcheck, etc.), compiler flags -Wall -Wextra. Nevertheless, none of them will substitute taking the time for reading a book on C programming.

Comment: `char* word = "";` creates a *string literal* of an *empty-string* in *read-only* memory. `scanf("%s",word);` invokes *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to write to `word` (and most likely a SegFault) Where do you allocate storage for `temp->val`? You don't assign strings in C, but must use `strcpy` (you can assign pointers, but if `name` ever changes in `main()` you will be changing `val->word` -- a copy is required after allocating storage for `val-word`.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`) - it's unnecessary and can mask a very real error if you fail to have the appropriate prototype in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your `head` is local to `add_to_list` function and will be destroyed once control exits `add_to_list`   function.

Also any changes done to `head` inside   `add_to_list` will not affect the original head `lst`.

**Solution:**

You can pass the reference of original head to insert in order to retain changes made in `add_to_list` as below.

```
void add_to_list(char* word, word_link **head);

void add_to_list(char* word, word_link **head){    
  int i; 
  word_link * temp = NULL;
  word_link * p = NULL;

  temp = (word_link*)malloc(sizeof(word_link));
  if (temp == NULL) return;

  temp->val = word;
  temp->next = NULL;

  if(*head == NULL){
    *head = temp;
  } else {
    p = *head;
    while(p->next != NULL){
      p = p->next;
   }
    p->next = temp;
  }
}
```

And you call `add_to_list` as below.

`add_to_list(word, &lst);`

**Another Issue:**

`char* word = "";` this will create `word` as pointer to immutable string literal. Modifying the `word` content `scanf("%s",word);` will  result in UB and since every time you are passing the same pointer to `add_to_list` every node in the list will point to same `word`.

You might want to declare it as below.

`char *word = malloc(256);`
Inside the while loop and pass it to `add_to_list`.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`) - it's unnecessary and can mask a very real error if you fail to have the appropriate prototype in scope.